Now able to add the yfinance flutter package yahoo_finance_data_reader
This is the package that I am trying to add in my Flutter project:
yahoo_finance_data_reader: ^1.0.11
But add soon as I run flutter pub get i face this issue:
flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies... (1.0s)

Downloading packages... (3.4s)

Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process.
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
in the directory open in another application.


I am experiencing the same issue when trying to get this package in github CI/CD pipeline on windows environment. Works fine with linux.
I isolated the issue to this specific package - all the other packages in my app can be downloaded using pub get. I tried retrying and sleeping between steps but with no luck so far.
I don't have solution yet, will update if I find something.
Edit: I believe this is the root cause:
https://github.com/ivofernandes/yahoo_finance_data_reader/issues/10
The package has a folder named AUX - this is forbidden on Windows as it is some legacy keyword. I can't even checkout this git repo on windows due to this issue.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
